# How do I define a pandas coercion for a custom dtype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a special implementation of a `date` dtype. For various reasons it isn't a `date` since that has its own set of issues.

For Pandas I would like to just have it treated exactly as if it was a builtin `datetime`.

So far I haven't been able to get around `TypeError: <class '__main__.SpecialTime'> is not convertible to datetime`

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.extensions import ExtensionDtype


class SpecialTime(ExtensionDtype):
    name = "SpecialTime"
    na_value = None

    @classmethod
    def construct_array_type(cls):
        return pd.arrays.DatetimeArray

    def __init__(self, year, month, day):
        self._date = date(year, month, day)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._date)

    def to_datetime(self):
        return datetime.combine(self._date, datetime.min.time())

    # add method to avoid TypeError: <class '__main__.SpecialTime'> is not convertible to datetime
    def __array__(self, dtype=None):
        return np.array([self.to_datetime()], dtype="datetime64[ns]")


pd.api.extensions.register_extension_dtype(SpecialTime)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_column": [
            SpecialTime(2022, 1, 1),
            SpecialTime(2023, 1, 2),
            SpecialTime(2024, 1, 3),
        ]
    }
)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df.convert_dtypes().dtypes)
print(df.astype("datetime64[ns]").dtypes)
```